# EF 4.1 code-first connectionstring in web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm having a bit of a nightmare day today. I've been working successfully on a code-first development locally and everything has been going along just fine with my db being dropped and recreated as required when the model changes. However, on attempting to 'upgrade' the project to a sqlserver2008 staging server on mydiscountasp.net, my problems began in earnest.  As the shared hosting databases cannot be dropped/recreated by the user, I took a local backup and restored it onto the server. One step closer.. I can see the database when I log into the server via sqlserver mgt studio and it all looks fine. However, I can't seem to figure out how to connect to the database via the web.config. I had started off using the humble ado.net sysntax for the connection string along the lines of:

```
<add name="MyWebSiteContext" 
  connectionString="Server=esql2k123.discountasp.net;
  Database=SQL2008R2_123456_test;uid=SQL2008R2_123456_test_user;pwd=mypassword;" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

this didn't work and gave an error saying that the keyword 'server' wasn't recognised. after much googling, it would appear that the issue could well be related to the `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` part.

So on changing this to `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` I was filled with a little hope. Alas, same story.

To cut a (very) long story short, I've tried many permutations (mutations being the operative word !! :)) but can't seem to strike the correct syntax requirement for the code-first ef connectionstring requirement.

Has anyone out there gone thro a similar hoop recently and found a working solution??

fingers, toes and eyes xx'd..

**[UPDATE]** i've managed to get my connection string to (ALMOST) work by formatting it as follows:

```
<add name="GBCWebSiteContext" 
connectionString="Data Source=esql2k123.discountasp.net;Initial Catalog=SQL2008R2_123456_test;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=SQL2008R2_123456_test_user;Password=mypass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I'm now able to stop and debug the controller action as it performs a linq select. HOWEVER, on attempting to return the rows, I now receive an exception which states: **A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow results from triggers' is true**

So, what's my final piece of the jigsaw here, is the an additional option in the connectionstring to negate this problem??

**[UPDATE 2]**
Hallellulah - I've cracked the nut. As I had remmed out the global.asax line:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyWebSiteContext>());
```

I hadn't realised that I needed to include a null reference to the `Database.SetInitializer()`.

lo and behold, the following sorted my problem:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyWebSiteContext>(null);
```

thank you everyone for the various suggestions, they helped me focus on the problem. So happy :)

Comment: What does your local connectionstring look like? You can likely make a slight modification to that, deploy it to the staging (an later to the production) environment and have it working again. EF needs quite a lot of metadata in the connectionstring, so I wouldn't try to write it from scratch by hand.

Comment: Tomas- the local connectionstring is the ef4.1 code-first convention based connectionstring. i.e. isn't declared in the web.config

Comment: In your SQL Server, can you run this?  `exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;`  
`RECONFIGURE;`  
`exec sp_configure 'disallow results from triggers',1;`  
`RECONFIGURE;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in essence, the answer to my problem was two-fold:

1. the connectionstring needed to be along the lines of (just pasting connectionstring info, all else remains the same as above):

   connectionString="Data Source=esql2k123.discountasp.net;Initial     Catalog=SQL2008R2_123456_test;Persist Security Info=True;**MultipleActiveResultSets=True**;User ID=SQL2008R2_123456_test_user;Password=mypass"
2. The global.asax Application_Start (or as is the case with my app, the ninject OnApplicationStarted()) needed to have a null `Database.SetInitializer<>()` function as remming out the existing:

`Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyWebSiteContext>());`

caused an issue.  Replacing this with `Database.SetInitializer<MyWebSiteContext>(null);`

fixed the problem wholesale.

thanks for sharing the journey and your thoughts and hopefully this will serve as a starting point for anyone else having similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Data source and Initial Catalog?

```
sqlConnectionString="data source=myServer.myDomain.com;initial catalog=mydbName;user id=myUid;password=myPwd"
```

Comment: Brian, yes, i tried that avenue earlier too, got a message along the lines of: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Comment: @Jim: This makes me think you have an issue with the credentials to authenticate to this database. This is quite common when you restore a database on another server since the unique IDs for the user names get messed up. Have you tried creating a new user name on the database and make sure you can connect to it from both SQL Management Studio and from your app?

Comment: hector, can connect from sqlmgtstud. can't say the same for the app - still a big mystery and no real tooling to trace the problem. very frustrating i can assure you.

Comment: Have you tried putting a <clear /> in before your connection string?

Answer (score 2):

Is the database server and the webserver on the same environment? have you tried `Server=localhost;` instead of `Server=esql2k123.discountasp.net;`?

Or alternatively, can you find out which ip address the database server has from where the web server is?

Comment: hi there, i don't think (i may be wrong tho) that it's a 'location of server issue. it's definitely a connectionstring 'syntax' problem - 99% certain. but thanks anyway

Comment: For my web site I have:    DataSource and not Server but if it works on your local development...

Comment: tricat - it only works locally due to the fact that i'm using code-first convention over config and thus it defaults to a hidden 'setting'. i'll have a look to see what the hidden setting reveals.